# Cannot access my phpMyAdmin DB - neither any related configuration file

Tags: mysql, django, phpmyadmin

I've been using a phpMyAdmin SQL DB in the past two years, which was pretty transparent to me.

I inherited it from a guy that set it up for my team, and I actually got nothing but a username, password, and a Django web project that's linked to that database.
Until today, any interaction with that DB was either via Django's ORM, or via the web UI of the phpMyAdmin site.

Today, suddenly, for the first time, I got the following error:

[image]

And that's it.

I've been googling this error, and read some stack overflow threads, but they all suggest editing some configuration files in /etc, but again, I have no clue what's that about and how or where do I access those file - all I know is my username and password to the website, and my Django project's ORM queries (I know it's sad, but that's the reality).

I'm the only one in the team that uses the DB, so nobody touched nothing for sure.

What can I do to fix that, or to start understanding what happened here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: phpmyadmin is only a gui for mysql written in php

Comment: maybe the databse was corrupted, see if you have a backup

Answer (score 1):

1. So , you have to open XAMPP Control Panel ->Click MySql Config->Click my.ini

It will open in notepad as shown in figure.

2. You have to write this line skip-grant-tables after [mysqld].

3.Open xamp folder ->PhpMyAdmin .You will see config.inc.php file in phpMyAdmin folder, just open it with notepad++

$cfg[‘Servers’][$i][‘host’] = ‘127.0.0.1’; This is default port number.

4. Resolve this issue by manually editing in the file “config.inc.php” located at “C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin”. Write “localhost:3307” within $cfg[‘Servers’][$i][‘host’] = ‘localhost:3307′; as shown given picture.
5. Save this changes. You can find port number as follows: Open XAMP->config->service port setting->mySql.

Now , you can access MyPhpAdmin.